# bitbake doesn't append sysroot to CPPFLAGS

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Hi I am using Makefile to build certain library using recipes. In my Makefile there are CPPFLAGS and includes which point to /lib and /usr/include but as sysroot is not appended ahead of these directories, it cannot find files. Shouldn't bitbake append the sysroot path automatically?

Comment: This is impossible to answer if you don't show how/why your Makefile refers to these paths.

Answer (score 1):

The sysroot is specified as part of CPP, bitbake -e shows this. The question is therefore why your makefile isn't using CPP. There is no need to put it in CPPFLAGS since its part of the CPP command.